# C# DataGridView with updatable DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and multiple objects containing data whit which I want to populate the DataGridView every time I switch between selecting one of those objects. I also want to update the data in those objects every time I edit the DataGridView.

The DataGridView already has predefined columns, some of them being a ComboBox column.

Say I have

```
public class OB()
{
    public DataTable data { get; private set; } = new DataTable();
}

obj1 = new OB();
obj2 = new OB();
.
.
.
public void some_selection_event(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ((OB)s).data;
}
```

If I edit `dataGridView1` while `obj1.data` is bound to its `DataSource` and then bind something else to it before binding `obj1.data` back to it again, `dataGridView1` show that it only remembers the number of rows it had whilst I  was editing it with `obj1.data` bound to its `DataSource`, and the data in the cells is lost, every cell is empty.

Is there a way that I can easily map a DataSource to a DataGridView and have then automatically update, or am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not understanding what the second to last paragraph is articulating. If the gird has a `DataSource` and the user makes changes to some of the cells in the grid… then the `DataSource` is updated at the same time to reflect those changes. Changing the grids data source should not remove the changes made in the previous `DataSource`. In other words, if you re-bind the grid to the previous `DataSource` then the previous changes made should still be there. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: A logical conclusion, my friend, but for me it's not like that. Switch back and forth, rebinding different DataSources, the only thing that reflects any changes were made is the number of empty rows in the DataGrid. 
Alos, maybe I wasn't clear enough about this but I edit the dataGrid directly from itself, not outside TextBox and not button to submit the changes. I think the EditMode is EditOnEnter

Comment: _”A logical conclusion, my friend, but for me it's not like that.”_ … It is not a “logical conclusion” … it is a FACT… and I can demonstrate this. My point is that… your “conclusion” that the data is not saved as you describe is not true. You may want to google… `DataAdapter`… Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates/reproduces your claim.

Answer (score 0):

If you have predefined `Columns` in your `DataGridView`, use `DataGridView.DataPropertyName` to make sure that the `DataSource` and `DataGridView` are both addressing the same data.